# Store data from byte array into queue then convert to char array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, char, queue

I've been trying to store a byte array into a Queue and when then queue reaches a certain length to empty the queue and convert everything to a char array. However I don't receive any output when performing this. Is there a reason why it's empty after using the queue? Thanks.

char Array being sent as bytes to C# app:

```
char Str[10] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'};
```

char array called **Str** is converted to bytes before reaching the app and becomes **data**

```
void Update()
{
    Queue<byte> myQueue = new Queue<byte>();
    Debug.Log("datalength: " + data.Length);
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[data.Length];
    if (data.Length == 20)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            myQueue.Enqueue(data[i]);
            byteArray[i] = myQueue.Dequeue();
        }
    }

    Debug.Log("byteArrayLength: " + byteArray.Length);
    char[] charArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, 20).ToCharArray();
    string s = PrintCharArray(charArray);
}

public static string PrintCharArray(char[] chars)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder("new byte[] { ");
    foreach (var b in chars)
    {
        sb.Append(b + ", ");
        Debug.Log(b.ToString());
    }
    sb.Append("}");


        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What is empty after using the queue? The queue is empty after `Dequeue()` of course.

Comment: You do realise that your queue is always empty, as you Dequeue it just afeter Enqueue, right? All your for loop is doing is copy data from `data` to `byteArray`.

Comment: Also, you're only doing something if you receive an array with exact 20 elements. You're probably geting no results because the array you're receiving contains more or less than 20 elements. Which based on the `Str` is 10 elements, that's why it's empty

Comment: Your for loop in Update ends up with a zero length queue.  Enqueue adds one item and then Dequeue removes the item.  So when the for loop ends you have no items in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

There are many erros on your code.

1. You're redeclaring `myQueue` everytime you execute the `Update` method, cleaning previous data. You must declare and initialize it outside the method, either as `static`, as a member of the class or passing it's reference to the `Update`.
2. Your code only runs if you receive exact 20 elements in the data array, but you receive 10
3. Your loop is only copying itens from one array to another, not using the queue

So this is a fixed code

```
static Queue<byte> myQueue = new Queue<byte>();

void Update()
{
    Debug.Log("datalength: " + data.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        myQueue.Enqueue(data[i]);        
    }

    if (myQueue.Count == 20)
    {

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[myQueue.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
        {
            byteArray[i] = myQueue.Dequeue();
        }

        Debug.Log("byteArrayLength: " + byteArray.Length);
        char[] charArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length).ToCharArray();
        string s = PrintCharArray(charArray);

    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sending the char array from Arduino and the data array becomes 20 because a C# char is 2 bytes and an Arduino char is 1 byte. I wanted to have a capacity of 20 in the queue, but thought I'd check this first. When I print data.Length I'm getting a length of 20 in my output.

Comment: @ConradAddo so... did you try my solution? What is the problem you're getting with it?